# “method saveas of object _workbook failed” error while trying to save an XLSM as CSV on a mapped server

Tags: vba, excel, csv, methods, save-as

Hello,
 I'm trying to save a xlsm file as a CSV on a server I mapped on my computer. 
 Here's the code:

```
CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "Y:\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "Project_Type_Test" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

VBA indicates that the bug comes form this line of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "Project_Type_Test" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

I tried to switch ActiveWorkbook by ThisWorkbook, but it did not change anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried adding an ErrorHandler? Also, where is the error message?

Comment: try copy the first sheet to a new workbook first then saving that workbook as csv.

Comment: It's working fine here.  ErrorHandler and verify the file path is correct?  Also, it helps to tell us what was the error message

Comment: @Alex I just noticed he posted the error message in the title... "*Method SaveAs of Object_Workbook failed*"

Comment: @Maldred right thanks i missed that.  OP can try from saving the file as .xlsm first into your C:\temp\ first and work from there if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it works fine for me if I set it to my hard drive.

```
Sub tst()Possibly try using the url instead of the mapped dive letter

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "C:\TEMP\" 'CHANGED THIS TO BE MY HD AND WORKS FINE
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "Project_Type_Test" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Possibly try using the url for the resource instead of the mapped drive letter

- "\\machine\path\"
- instead of "Y:\"

Comment: It also works for me when I try to save it on my hard drive. However, the url I need to use is is a cloud url. I realized that I am able to reach this specific path, since it asks me if I want to overwrite the existing file with the same name. Thus, the problem is really coming from this line of the code: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "Project_Type_Test" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

And the error is the following: Method'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed